# Fibonacci numbers and proving using mathematical induction

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I need to prove the rule below using Mathematical proof by induction but actually I'm stuck in the middle of the proving.

$$F_n^2 - F_{n-1}F_{n+1} = (-1)^{n+1} {~\rm for~} n>1$$

If someone can help that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming you're stuck on the inductive part. If you want to show that $$F_{k+1}^2-F_k F_{k+2}=(-1)^{k+2},$$ notice that you have a $F_{k+2}$ on the left hand side which you should get rid of. Use the identity $F_{k+2}=F_{k+1}+F_k$, multiply out, look for something to replace, and then simplify your answer. (You'll have to use the Fibonacci definition again, if I remember correctly.)

Comment: @Christopher Carl Heckman. Thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$F_{n+1} = F_n+F_{n-1}\quad\mbox{for all }n\ge2,$$
which follows that
\begin{align}
F_{n+1}^2 - F_{n}F_{n+2} 
&=F_{n+1}(F_{n}+F_{n-1}) - F_{n}(F_{n+1}+F_{n}) \\
&=F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-F_{n}^2\\
&= -(-1)^{n+1}\\
&=(-1)^{n+2}.
\end{align}